# Data is not reloaded on page refresh

Tags: richfaces, spring-webflow, page-refresh

In project page, after clicking refresh in browser, no data is changed.
Basically, I want to restart flow on page reload (F5) to trigger <on-start> state in flow to reload my data.

Answer (score 3):

try `<on-render>` tag instead of `<on-start>`

**NOTE** `<on-render>` gets executed every time you render page, prefer `<on-start>` wherever possible